# Get data from script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i get the email address from this script

```
<script>
    var wcRQlKjfP = 'sales@websaucestudio##.com';
    var wcRQlKjfP = wcRQlKjfP.split('#');
    document.getElementById('wcRQlKjfP').innerHTML = wcRQlKjfP[0]+wcRQlKjfP[2]+wcRQlKjfP[1]; document.getElementById('wcRQlKjfP').href = 'mailto:'+wcRQlKjfP[0]+wcRQlKjfP[2]+wcRQlKjfP[1];
</script>
```

Help me!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of obfuscated nonsense is that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the email? Display it in a tag?

Comment: Why are you utilising a part of the split that has nothing in it? I can't see any reason for that **other** than obfuscation.

Comment: What happen to your variable naming? A cat running across your keyboard? You want to remove the `#` sign in your variable, right?

Comment: I am learning about scrapy a website and i want to get email address in this script

Answer (score 1):

Although your variable has a strange name, all you need to do is combine the three parts (`wcRQlKjfP[0] + wcRQlKjfP[2]`).

`wcRQlKjfP[1]` can be completely ignored, as it evaluates to an empty string.

Here I'm logging the result to the console, but you could always assign to a new variable and then reference that variable.

```js
var wcRQlKjfP = 'sales@websaucestudio##.com';
var wcRQlKjfP = wcRQlKjfP.split('#');
document.getElementById('wcRQlKjfP').innerHTML = wcRQlKjfP[0] + wcRQlKjfP[2] + wcRQlKjfP[1];
document.getElementById('wcRQlKjfP').href = 'mailto:' + wcRQlKjfP[0] + wcRQlKjfP[2] + wcRQlKjfP[1];

console.log(wcRQlKjfP[0] + wcRQlKjfP[2]);
```

```html
<a id="wcRQlKjfP"></a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Nice answer. But I think `wcRQlKjfP[1]` can be ignored :)

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala -- correct. I've updated my answer to remove it :)